# Oracle Data Modeler: Switch to Crow's Foot notation

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the standard notation:

[image]

I would like something like this:

[image]

Can be it changed somehow?

Comment: both of those diagrams already use "Crow's Foot" notation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know we can change the notation of the logical modelling tool but not the physical diagrammer.

However, you should ask this question on the OTN Data Modeler forum, which [you can find here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1317&start=0).  Members of the SQL Dev team regularly respond on that forum; they may know of a way to do this, and, if not, you can suggest it as a change request.